# How can I add headers to my soap request in Java?

Tags: java, soap

I am trying to add two headers to my soap request but I am getting the error while calling that SOAP WS.

com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed .

Below is my code and SOAP request where I want to add headers.
Can someone let me know where am I going wrong?

I had tried calling the WS from SOAP UI providing the headers along and its working fine.

```
private SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest(String request) throws Exception {

        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        InputStream stream = new 
        ByteArrayInputStream(request.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage(new MimeHeaders(), stream);
        soapMessage.getMimeHeaders().addHeader("Authorization", "Auth_value");
        soapMessage.getMimeHeaders().addHeader("Header1", "header_value1");

        }
        soapMessage.saveChanges();
        return soapMessage;
    }   

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:prov="http://abc/ProvisioningServiceMessages">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
     <prov:RetrieveRequest>
     <prov:KeyPropertyLookup>
        <prov1:NodeType xmlns:prov1="http://abc/ProvisioningServiceMessages">ABC</prov1:NodeType>
        <prov1:PropertyName xmlns:prov1="http://abc/ProvisioningServiceMessages">DEF</prov1:PropertyName>
        <prov1:PropertyValue xmlns:prov1="http://abc/ProvisioningServiceMessages">12345</prov1:PropertyValue>
     </prov:KeyPropertyLookup>
     <prov:Projections>
        <prov:IncludeChildren>true</prov:IncludeChildren>
     </prov:Projections>
     </prov:RetrieveRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Have you tried [getSOAPHeader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage.html#getSOAPHeader())?

Comment: No , I hadn't tried that and I am lacking the workarounds for that too. Can you help me out? Thanks in advance.